# Круглый прогресс с возможность задавать ему фон

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Прогресс бару нужно задавать значение, в линейном прогресс баре, можно две png наложить друг на друга и отрисовывать у верхнего только какую то часть, а у круглого такое не прокатит. Задавать в xml drawable можно, но там особо красоту не наведешь, нужно заморочиться, чтобы каждый раз делать красивые подходящий по дизайну фон.  Какие есть возможности для реализации этого дела ?

Comment: можно было бы достичь успеха в этом вопросе, если найти способ рисовать рисовать по кругу с заданной толщиной . Или может анимации использовать? для каждого последующего шага разные изображения ..

Comment: может вариант с анимацией прокатит? Есть анимация, от начала отрисовки до полного круга 100 % , мы задаем процент до какого места анимация должна прорисоваться .. вот только какими средствами андроид это можно осуществить